# How to accept keyboard input within XCode 8 Playground using Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I used to use this snippet to read keyboard input from XCode's Playground. And it worked very well. Today, I just updated my XCode to v.8 and Swift v.3. After a little bit modification here and there due to Swift 3 incompatibility, I got this code compiled without error. But it doesn't work. No keyboard input is taken. It just stucks.

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

func input() -> String {
  let keyboard  = FileHandle.standardInput
  let inputData = keyboard.availableData
  let encoding  = String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
  let strData   = String(data: inputData, encoding: encoding)
  return strData! as String
}

func write(_ txt: String) {
  print(txt, terminator: "")
}

func writeln(_ txt: String) {
  print(txt)
}

func read() -> String {
  return input().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}

func readln() -> String {
  return input()
}

/* main program */

write("Enter your name: ")
let s = readln()
```

So, does anyone know how to make it works (again)? Thank you.

Regards,

~Bee